# When running GitHub actions with a concurrency restriction, can I get workflow runs enqueued rather than cancelled?

Tags: concurrency, queue, github-actions

[The documentation of GitHub actions says](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency):

> You can use jobs.<job_id>.concurrency to ensure that only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time.
>
> ...
>
> When a concurrent job or workflow is queued, if another job or workflow using the same concurrency group in the repository is in progress, the queued job or workflow will be pending. **Any previously pending job or workflow in the concurrency group will be canceled.**

It is annoying that previously pending jobs get cancelled. Evidently the orchestration logic can only maintain a tiny "queue" of one (1) pending job.

I would like to be able to have multiple jobs enqueued. I.e., if I trigger 5 jobs in rapid succession, and they all belong to the same concurrency group, then the first one starts to run immediately (when a runner is availble) and the next 4 get enqueued and wait for their turn to run, one at a time.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or will I need to request this as a feature from GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a reusable workflow that can force runs of a workflow to run consecutively (i.e., in order). This solved my problem.

Here is the reusable workflow: https://github.com/mktcode/consecutive-workflow-action